# JMeter Beanshell - save file as pdf

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, beanshell

Currently I am saving variable values in ".txt" file using beanshell post-processor, I want to save  variable value into a pdf file  , is there any way I can achieve it?

To save variable value in a text file, i am using below code:

```
var1= vars.get("myVariableValue"); 

f = new FileOutputStream("D:/myTextFile.txt",true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
p.println(var1);

f.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need an external library like [PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for this
2. You will need to have PDFBox in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead)

Assuming all above:

1. Download `pdfbox-2.0.24.jar` and `fontbox-2.0.24.jar` files and put them to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the "jar"
3. Add an appropriate JSR223 Test Element to your Test Plan
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables

   JMeterVariables vars = new JMeterVariables()
   vars.put('myVariableValue','hello')

   def document = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument()
   def page = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage()
   document.addPage(page)

   def contentStream = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream(document, page)

   contentStream.setFont(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.COURIER, 12)
   contentStream.beginText()
   contentStream.showText(vars.get('myVariableValue'))
   contentStream.endText()
   contentStream.close()

   document.save('myPDFFile.pdf')
   document.close()
   ```
5. That's it, you should see `myPDFFile.pdf` file in JMeter's working directory

Comment: thanks a lot Dmitri, it worked as expected. just a doubt, what to do if I want to print one variable on 1st page and another on 2nd page in my pdf? 
because right now everything is getting printed on single page.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I figured it out :) , thanks !!